# How to change object properties inside a json file

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I have a huge JSON file called data.json filled with objects with equal properties.
A sample of an object is this:

```
  {
    "directory": "directory_here",
    "posted": false,
    "date": null
  }
```

In my script, I am using fs.readFile reading the data.json file if posted is false, if it is then run some functions and then change posted to true and also change date from null to the current date. So I need to change the properties inside the data.json file. How can I do that?

Comment: All this objects are in array or not ?

Comment: yes, they are inside one array

Answer (score 1):

Except for a few pathological cases you cannot directly edit the contents of a JSON text file. Instead, you would need to *either* **(a)** read-modify-write the data, or **(b)** switch to a different storage format that *does* allow in-place editing.

If you (have to) stick with JSON, you have two main choices:

1. Read the file in chunks, parsing to JSON as you go. When you get a complete object, modify it as required then write it to a *new* file. After the whole file has been read, and all objects written, you can replace the original file with the newly-created one.
2. Read and parse the whole file into an array of objects. Make the required changes to all objects and then write the entire array (in JSON format) over the top of the original file. (Or, for extra safety, you could write to a new file and replace the original if there were no problems).

The second approach is probably easier to write, but will consume more memory.

A possible alternative (that I suspect won't be appropriate in your case) would be to switch to a storage format that *does* allow in-place editing. This could be a file of fixed record length records, or something like an SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

Here `arr` is Array of object

```
arr.forEach((obj)=>{
  if(!obj.posted) obj.posted = true;
  if(!obj.date) obj.date = new Date()
})
```

Comment: And can I edit the object directly inside the json file?

Comment: Yes you can, but for that you've to use file system to read file and do other operation.